# Draw a half ellipse in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can we draw a half ellipse using Tikz?
For example, I have the following drawing and I want to remove (or hide) part of the ellipse.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please show us what you try so far. which part of ellipse you like to remove?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no MWE and this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Comment: It's very much on-topic. It's just not a perfectly written answer. This shouldn't be closed.

Comment: I meant "not a perfectly written *question*."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course you can draw half an ellipse with `arc`. The syntax is `arc(<start angle>:<end angle>:<radius X> and <radius Y>)`, here are two examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) arc(0:180:2cm and 1cm);
 \draw (4,0) arc(90:270:2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove a part of an existing ellipse and in addition to the marmot response, there is the `\clip` command which allows you to delimit the drawing area of all the following paths. This makes it possible to remove any part of an ellipse.

In the examples below, the area colored green is the area that delimits the following drawings.

The ellipse is built here with the `circle` command.

[image: ellipse-clip]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\fill[green](-1,0)rectangle(1,.5);
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\clip(-1,0)rectangle(1,.5);
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2)}]
\fill[green](-1,-.5)rectangle(0,.5);
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(3,-2)}]
\clip(-1,-.5)rectangle(0,.5);
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-4)}]
\fill[green](0,-1)--(100:.8)--(-20:1.2)--cycle;
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(3,-4)}]
\clip(0,-1)--(100:1.2)--(-20:1.2)--cycle;
\draw (0,0) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```